# Copies of holomorphic cylinders VS. Unbranched cover of cylinder.

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $(\hat{W}, \hat{\omega})$ be symplectic manifold with cylindrical ends.(Completion of symplectic cobordism)  Given a almost complex structure $J$, let $u$ be a  $J$-holomorphic curve with finite energy.

I always confuse the following two terminologies:

1. $u$ is $m$-copies of simple holomorphic cylinders.
2. $u$ is unbranched cover of a simple holomorphic cylinder.

Are these two concepts the same? If not, what is the different?

Comment: As an analogy, consider a smooth embedding $f : S^1 \to M$ (note that the cylinder is diffeomorphic to $S^1 \times (0,1)$). On the one hand, "$m$ copies of $S^1$" means the disjoint union $\sqcup^m S^1$ and "$m$ copies of $f$" means the map $\sqcup^m f : \sqcup^m S^1 \to M$ which restricts to $f$ on each factor $S^1$. On the other hand, there is a covering map $c : S^1 \to S^1$ of degree $m$, and the map $f \circ c : S^1 \to M$ is, so to speak, a $m$-cover of the embedding $f$ (or of the embedded circle $f(S^1)$). What's the difference between $\sqcup^m f$ and $f \circ c$?

Comment: Thanks, I think I get the points. I have one more question: For covered of holomorphic cylinder, the transversality doesn't hold in general.   In the case when $u$ is just copies of simple holomorphic cylinders,  then the transversality always hold? (In my understanding, we can regards them as different simple curves with different domains,  and then we can prove the transversality as usual.  )